# Facing issue of storing the token in local storage in angular, particularly in login component

Tags: javascript, angular, authorization

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

   

  LoginUserData= { email: '', password:'' };

  constructor( private _auth : AuthService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  luser()
  {
    
    this._auth.loginUser(this.LoginUserData)
    .subscribe( Response =>{
        
      console.log(Response);
      localStorage.setItem('token',Response.token)



    })


  }

}
```

I am getting error in `localStorage.setItem('token',Response.token)` , and when I'm trying to store token in register page, it has been stored in localStorage

> Error: Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'.ts(2339)

This is the error, and this is the [GitHub file](https://github.com/kishore05102004/angular-authentication).

Comment: so you think given information is enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Did your check your `Response` object, ie does it really have the structure and properties you assume it has?

Comment: @MohitSharma , Sir, kindly apologise for that, am a student , i dont  know, how to use, stackflow, that's why I had attach the github file on my question, am trying to learn authentication, but i face some issuess on that!  My mentor  said that, upload the code and question to ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no definition of type `Response` in your code. `Response` is also a reserved word I think. For your own good sake, stop naming variable with capital letters.

Try this to save the token in LS.

```
this._auth.loginUser(this.LoginUserData)
.subscribe((response: any) => {
  console.log(response);
  localStorage.setItem('token', response.token);
})
```

I assume that your token is `string`. If it's not, you will need to do `localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.token));`